# How to replace compression elbow for flexible connector with stop valve

Tags: plumbing, pipe

On the picture you can see 2 copper pipes coming out of the elbows, the ones that have cables on them, these go to the bathtub tap. I want to replace these with flexible connectors.

The problem is that these are compression elbows so need to replace those first.

Ideally I would like to have an angled compression elbow with stop valve and 22mm male connector. Into which I could then connect female to female flexible tap connector. But I cannot find such elbow.

I found one you can see attached on the second picture but it doesn’t have a stop valve. What’s the best way to do this if I want both flexible pipe and a stop valve?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find the elbow you want with integrated stop valve, you can use the compression-to-threaded elbow you found, attach a separate stop-valve to the threaded end and then use a straight threaded-to-threaded connector to connect your flexible tap connector to the stop-valve.